# HubSpot API - Search contact by phone

Tags: api, hubspot

I understand that HubSpot api provides an endpoint to search contact by name or email?

Is there a way to search a contact by phone number with the API?

Comment: This API document can help you to search contact by phone number. https://legacydocs.hubspot.com/docs/methods/contacts/search_contacts

Answer (score 1):

Below Python code works on my side.
[This page](https://theobogroup.com/diving-into-the-new-hubspot-api-v3-with-real-world-use-cases/) looks very useful.

Cheers!

```
import hubspot
from pprint import pprint
from hubspot.crm.deals import PublicObjectSearchRequest, ApiException

api_key = "your api key"

test_search_url = f'https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v3/objects/contact/search?hapikey='+api_key
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}

payload = {
        "filterGroups": [
            {
                "filters": [
                    {
                        "propertyName": "phone",
                        "operator": "EQ",
                        "value": "1234567"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "properties": [
            "firstname", "lastname", "email", "hs_object_id" 
        ]
    }
    
res = requests.post(test_search_url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))

res.json()

####Output####
# {'total': 1,
#  'results': [{'id': '13701',
#    'properties': {'createdate': '2022-02-10T07:27:18.733Z',
#     'email': 'adi@XXX.com',
#     'firstname': 'XXX K.',
#     'hs_object_id': '13701',
#     'lastmodifieddate': '2022-02-10T07:28:01.033Z',
#     'lastname': None},
#    'createdAt': '2022-02-10T07:27:18.733Z',
#    'updatedAt': '2022-02-10T07:28:01.033Z',
#    'archived': False}]
# }
```

Answer (score 0):

For an online tool with a free trial, you can try [Acho](https://acho.io). Our company uses it to fetch data from HubSpot and use its built-in search bar to search for a specific contact that we need.

Answer (score 0):

I have a function for exactly that written in Python.

The function returns an array of contact's IDs, but you can retrieve other properties if you want, you have to add them in `properties=["id"]`

```
from hubspot import HubSpot
from hubspot.crm.contacts import ApiException
from hubspot.crm.contacts import PublicObjectSearchRequest

def get_contacts_by_phone(phone):


    api_client = HubSpot()
    api_client = HubSpot(access_token=YOUR_TOKEN)

    public_object_search_request = PublicObjectSearchRequest(
        filter_groups=[],
        sorts=[{"propertyName": "phone", "direction": "DESCENDING"}],
        properties=["id"],
        query=phone,
        limit=100,
    )
    try:
        api_response = api_client.crm.contacts.search_api.do_search(
            public_object_search_request=public_object_search_request
        )
        print(api_response)
        contacts_ids = []
        for contact in api_response.results:
            contacts_ids.append(contact.id)

        return contacts_ids

    except ApiException as e:
        print("Exception when calling search_api->do_search: %s\n" % e)
```